# how to performSegue to generic UIViewController class ?? CAST ERROR

Tags: swift, generics, segue

I want to perform segue from viewController to storyVC and pass storyID with segue. I am using storyVC as generic class because my presenter depends upon the type of the story.

Source View Controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
let segueIdentifier = "storyDetail"

@IBOutlet weak var segueButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func segueButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdentifier, sender: Any?.self)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == segueIdentifier {
        let storyID = 1
        let cType = "place"

        let destVC = segue.destination as! Story<Any>
        destVC.storyID = storyID
        destVC.storyType = cType
    }
 }

}
```

Generic Destination View Controller

```
class Story<T>: UIViewController {
var storyPresenter: T?

var storyID: Int = 0

var storyType: String = ""

//class functions
}
```

ERROR WITH CASTING

`let destVC = segue.destination as! Story<Any>`

ERROR MESSAGE

`Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' to 'storyModel.Story<Any>'`

Comment: May I suggest that you should not be using generics here, this seems like a case where subclasses will do what you want. I am partially saying that, because until recently you could not make generics of ObjC classes (like UIViewController) although that has changed recently.

Comment: @Walter based on storyType I would set the type of StoryPresenter and I will try to do it inside the init method. eg. if `storytype == "place"` then `storyPresenter: PlacePresenter`

Comment: So, if you had a class like `StoryPresenter` and it had subclasses like `PlacePresenter`, `ScenePresenter` etc. Then you would just have your `Story` class inherit from `UIViewController` and set your `var storyPresenter: StoryPresenter?` so that you could set it like you want. Anything common to all `StoryPresenters` would go into the main class

Comment: If you are setting `storyID` and `cType` statically like that then you will be fine, since you know the Story Presenter at design time. However, if you're planning to let those two values change at runtime, then maybe you want to go a slightly different direction. Maybe you have lots of segues to the different Presenter types. it's hard to know without understanding way more of your project.

Comment: How have to setup the Story<T> view controller in the storyboard?

Comment: @Walter once i set `var storyPresenter: StoryPresenter?` how can I change it to like `storyPresenter: PlacePresenter` Error I get `Cannot assign value of type 'PlacePresenter' to type 'StoryPresenter?'`.

Comment: If you have a class called `StoryPresenter` then all of your presenters need to be subclasses of that class. So, you would expect to see something like `class PlacePresenter: StoryPresenter` in the definition for the Place Presenter class. It's an extra class not present in your original code snippets.